# Finding a Particular Solution Curve

Tags: integration

Question states:

Find the equation of the curve that passes through the point (1,3) and has a slope of $\frac{y}{x^2}$ at any point $(x,y).$

Solution is as follows.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x^2}$$

separating variables and integrating, we get

$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \frac{dx}{x^2}, y \neq 0$$
$$y=Ce^{-1/x}$$

applying the initial condition, we find that $C=3e$, so we get

$$y=3e^{(x-1)/x}.$$

I totally understand all the steps and answer above. But the solution also states:

"Because the solution is not defined at $x=0$ and the initial condition is given at $x=1, x$ is restricted to positive values ($x >0$)."

Here's my question: why can't $x$ be negative? Why does $x$ being $1$ have anything to do with the positive restriction? I understand why $x$ cannot be zero, but I do not get why $x$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Some theorems about existence and uniqueness of solutions require definition domain to be connected.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, the curve will always have negative $x$ coordinates (the curve can't pass the line $x=0$ because it will diverge to infinity by the slope condition) and can't pass though the point $(1,3)$ which has $x$ positive.

Comment: Thanks Joanpemo and Michael Burr. I now see that the left-sided limit (of the function $y = 3e^{(x-1)/x}$ as $x$ approaches 0) is infinity. But wouldn't the solution still be correct if we limit the domain to include all real numbers except 0?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. This is not a solution, only a graphical representation displaying the vector field $(1,y/x^2)$ in the first quadrant (how will it be in the second quadrant ?) and the solution curves for values of the constant including $C=3$.

It is valuable to have a little sketch of the vector field associated with a differential equation.

[image]